# Memory Warnings and unused image assets

Tags: ios, image, memory-management

Can unused image files in the app bundle drain the memory of an iOS Device and eventually lead to a memory warning that terminates an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Unused files in the app bundle just take up disk space and of course bandwidth when downloading the app. But they consume no memory at runtime.